# django LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL strange behavior

Tags: django, wsgi, django-settings

I've got a django (1.4.5) site on sub path /foo.

In my setting.py I have the following set.  All access requires login.

```
LOGIN_URL='/foo/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/foo/'
```

I'm experiencing strange behavior.  When I go to `https://my.site.com/foo/`  I get redirected with the proper query string .. `https://my.site.com/foo/login/?next=/foo/`

however when I go to `https://my.site.com/foo` (with no trailing slash) I get redirected to 
`https:// my.site.com/foo/login/?next=/`

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Do you have APPEND_SLASH in your settings.py set to False?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash  Also, how are you enforcing that all pages require login?

Comment: I don't have APPEND_SLASH explicitly set in my settings.py.  I understand the default is true.  The views.py has @login_required for each of the views.  And when trying to navigate directly to one of those pages https://my.site.com/foo/page1 I get properly redirected to the login page with the correct query string my.site.com/foo/login/?next=/foo/page1/

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that behavior here.  I'd suggest trying to debug the `login_required` decorator to see how it constructed the `next` argument.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a closer look at the decorators.

Comment: in a way it was the decorator.  Initially it was set to `@login_required` with no explicit redirect, but once changed to `@login_required(redirect_field_name='/foo/')` things started working properly.  What I'm still scratching my head about is that it seems that, when left blank, `@login_redirect` should be getting the redirect_filed_name from the settings.py. Is that correct?